# HDMI audio not working in Xubuntu 18.04, audio device found but not listed by aplay

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi

I tried to put my old laptop back to use, but didn't find any way to get HDMI audio output working.

The HDMI audio device is listed with `lspci -nnk`, `xandr --verbose` shows `audio: auto supported: off, on, auto` for the HDMI device, and `cat /proc/asound/cards` also shows it.

> ```
> 01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS600M [Radeon Xpress 1250] [1002:7942]
>   Subsystem: LG Electronics, Inc. RS600M [Radeon Xpress 1250] [1854:011b]
>   Kernel driver in use: radeon
>   Kernel modules: radeon
> 01:05.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS600 HDMI Audio [Radeon Xpress 1250] [1002:793b]
>   Subsystem: LG Electronics, Inc. RS600 HDMI Audio [Radeon Xpress 1250] [1854:011b]
>   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
> ```

---

> ```
>  2 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
>                       HDA ATI HDMI at 0xdfeec000 irq 25
> ```

On the other hand, HDMI doesn't appear in `aplay -l`, `pacmd list-cards`, `alsamixer` or `pavucontrol`. There are HDMI devices listed in `aplay -L` but without device numbers.

I also found this in /etc/default/grub:

> ```
>  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
> ```

From some previous time struggling with HDMI audio, probably. I don't remember if HDMI audio has worked on this laptop before.

Most HDMI audio instructions I've been able to find have the HDMI audio device already listed in `aplay -l` and the issue concerns PulseAudio or graphical audio settings. I've found very little where the device doesn't even show up in `aplay -l`.

I've tried

- adding the line `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and rebooting
- `sudo update-grub` and reboot, with and without the `radeon.audio=1`
- setting audio to on with xrandr
- `sudo alsa force-reload`

The latter output this:

> ```
> Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer).
> Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-usb-audio snd-usbmidi-lib snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-timer
> ```

Here's the my output of ALSA Information Script: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0b6b62b0ed35af096c97afbdfca4fbbd523f23c1

Is there anything else I could try to get the audio working?

Answer (score 1):

I came to your post while searching same problem for Xubuntu 18.04 but worked without any issue in mint xface or other mint and ubuntu. I have dell inspiron 3420 i5 3210 laptop with nvidia 620M graphic card. I too was unable to find port configuration option under volume control  menu. Solution worked for me,

- Search 'pulseaudio volume' in 'Software'.
  find 'PulseAudio Volume Control'..
- First option Installed by default for "PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) is a simple GTK+ based volume control tool (mixer) for the PulseAudio sound server" (in which I was unable to find configuration option initially.
- Second Option Not Installed by default "Qt port of volume control pavucontrol of sound server PulseAudio." (in this section it is clearly mentioned for applicability for desktop environment.
- Installed second option alongside. Launched directly by launch button in the option (they appear same in menu search). Voila ! there was option for configuration for sound output. (connect HDMI Display (or TV) to laptop otherwise option may not come)
- Remark:
- I did not changed option to hdmi audio output from here. I went back to volume control option from task bar Icon--- audio mixer. Configuration Option was there.
- Just to crosscheck, go to audio mixer before installation of new volume control and search for configuration option next to input by clicking arrow. If it is not there then new installation of volume control (Qt based) replaced old one or revoked in old one. You may confirm.
- I am new to Linux and leaning to use.